# Cookie Clicker-like point counter in Java libGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

I am trying to make a Cookie Clicker-like game using libGDX in Java.
In Cookie Clicker games there is something called cPs, which is cookies/points per second. And that number can be huge. But instead of adding X points per second, the game is adding 1 point X times per second.

I am trying to do same thing using double variables. It looks something like this right now:

```
if (deltaTime > (1/pointsPerSecond)) {
        score += 1;
        deltaTime = 0;
    }
```

But with numbers like 300 points per second, the counter just can't keep up with adding points. What is the best solution to this?

Comment: Replace all your code above with `score += deltaTime * pointsPerSecond`. Although if you scale up as much Cookie Clicker does, a long might not have enough resolution. You might need a long for the first 9 significant digits, and a second long to track the next 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your help.

I manage to do it by dividing my point per second by 30 and adding them 30 times per second instead of adding them XXXX times per second 1 by 1 point. This way it looks like points are constantly increasing.

Have a nice day every1 :)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using Input Processor
[check out event handling here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Event-handling)

and in the `touchDown(....)` method, I would try to record down the time between each click and amplify that to seconds

for example the time taken between two clicks are 0.2s, then you are getting 1/0.2 = 5 clicks per second.

you can use `System.currentTimeMillis();` for your purpose and subtract the time of the current click to the previous click.